# Differential Equation In Distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

I need to find all  $u \in \mathcal{D}'$ ( space of distributions) such that

$ e^x (e^{-x} u ) ' = \delta_0 +1$.

For any $\phi \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we have

$\langle e^x (e^{-x} u ) '  , \phi \rangle = \langle \delta_0 +1, \phi\rangle$ and so

$\langle u   , e^{-x}(e^x\phi) ' \rangle = \phi(0)+ \langle 1, \phi\rangle$

$\langle u   ,  \phi+\phi ' \rangle = \phi(0)+ \langle 1, \phi\rangle$.

$\langle u   ,  \phi\rangle+\langle u, \phi ' \rangle = \phi(0)+ \langle 1, \phi\rangle$.

How should I continue from here ?

Thanks.

Comment: I changed ${}=< e^x ( e^{-x}u)',\varphi>$ to ${}=\langle e^x ( e^{-x}u)',\varphi\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

You have the equation $$e^x(e^{-x}u)'=\delta_0+1.$$
First step is to notice that the function $x\to e^{x}$ is $C^\infty$, strictly positive everywhere, hence we can safely divide by it both sides of the  equation without producing and/or losing solutions. Thus, we get

$$ (e^{-x}u)'=e^{-x}\delta_0+e^{-x}=\delta_0+e^{-x}.$$

It is easy to take the antiderivative of the right hand side: if $H$ is the Heavyside function and $c\in \Bbb C$, we obtain
$$e^{-x}u = H(x)-e^{-x}+c.$$

By the similar argument we can safely divide by $e^{-x}$ to obtain
$$ u = H(x)e^{ x}-1+ce^{ x}.$$